Redirecting output from an executable in Windows batch file not working
From within a batch file, I'm trying to install some components for Visual Studio without printing anything to the command prompt, but writing
"%programfiles(x86)%\microsoft visual studio\installer\setup" modify --quiet ^
--installpath "%programfiles%\microsoft visual studio\2022\community" ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows11SDK.22621 > nul 2> nul

doesn't seem to redirect all the output (or any of it for that matter).
The output I get looks like
[0888:0001][2024-12-30T19:43:22] Saving the current locale (en-US) to user.json.
[0888:0001][2024-12-30T19:43:22] Setting the telemetry services
[0888:0004][2024-12-30T19:43:22] Creating a new telemetry service.
[0888:0001][2024-12-30T19:43:22] Visual Studio Installer Version: 3.12.2149
...
[0888:0001][2024-12-30T19:43:22] Getting singleton lock. Mutex name: DevdivInstallerUI
...

(ellipses added by me).
What am I doing wrong?

The syntax I use for redirecting stdout and stderr is: command >nul 2>&1 If the program is writing to the console device you cannot redirect it.

Unfortunately this doesn't help. Even command > foo.txt 2> bar.txt still outputs lots of text to cmd.

What doesn't help? Your response to @Squashman does not use the syntax they offered and seemingly ignores their clear last sentence! Incidentally, I'd also use @(command) 1>NUL 2>&1.

Sorry, I was trying to say that I tried the > nul 2>&1 syntax and that didn't work, and I also tried explicitly redirecting output to two separate files, which didn't work either. Your suggestion didn't work either sadly. It might be the case that the program is writing to the console device.
